# Zip with repeats to preexisting dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the form:

```
my_dict = {'apples': 'NA', 'pears': 'NA', 'oranges': 'NA'}
```

and a zip that looks like:

```
my_zip = {([10, 10], 'apples'), ([100, 2], 'apples')}
```

I'd like to add those values to my_dict to yield this:

```
{'apples': [[10,10], [100, 2]], 'pears': 'NA', 'oranges': 'NA'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use a [`defauldict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_zip = [([10, 10], 'apples'), ([100, 2], 'apples')]
d = defaultdict(list)
for v, k in my_zip:
    d[k].append(v)
```

From there, if you really want your `'NA'` for non-existent values, you can `d.get('oranges', 'NA')`, or another trick would be to reset the `default_factory`:

```
d.default_factory = lambda: 'NA'
```

Though I'm not sure I recommend this one.  Usually I advocate setting it to `None` when you're done using the "default" behavior of your `defaultdict`.

You can also iterate over the original keys and just set the defaults to `'NA'`:

```
d.default_factory = None  # now d behaves like a regular dict
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    d.setdefault(key, val)
```

Comment: "NA" is actually content in an of its self, so it needs to be present as is. Thanks for the answer.